# How to connect to internet during installation of Ubuntu Mini ISO in virtualbox?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, ubuntu-minimal

I am using VirtualBox, and I am trying to install Unity as said in [this link](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-perform-clean-ubuntu-1804-with.html). I am able to install Ubuntu Mini, and get the tty. I am not able to proceed further, when I do

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

I tried (as per the feedback from the terminal)

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop --fix-missing
```

I am getting hundreds of error messages like

```
Failed to fetch, cannot initiate connection, network is unreachable [IP 44.255.166.254 80].
```

[image: Screenshot]

My Internet connection is perfectly OK on the host machine. How to fix this?

Comment: First check whether you have an working internet connection. `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Have you confirmed that the network settings allow the VM to access the Internet? Bridged mode is generally the one to go with for VirtualBox.

Comment: Yes. The VM can access the Internet. ping 8.8.8.8 gave the result average ping time to be 26 ms with no packet loss.